# How do Ravenloft powers checks work with scrolls?

Tags: magic-items, adnd-2e, ravenloft

For spells that require a powers check when cast in Ravenloft, when should the check happen for scrolls: during creation, at the time of the scroll's use, or both?

Comment: Has the DM made a house rule that makes scribing a scroll a reasonable endeavor? Or does scribing a scroll remain as difficult as the core books (vaguely) say?

Comment: I'm the DM, so I don't mind information that addresses all variables. No house rules per say, I just make access to the fine quality ingredients reasonable. The party is lower level and has just acquired these scrolls, so use will come up first. I want to be prepared for creation as well though.

Comment: O, wow. So the ink and paper recipes are widely known *and* the ingredients are easily acquired? That's scary even for Ravenloft! `:-)`

Comment: Even if the PCs never scribe scrolls themselves, this is still important lore.  Imagine a Domain ruled by someone whose crime that caused their conversion was writing scrolls of Evil spells...

Comment: I know the 2e DMG states that just because you know a spell doesn't mean you know how to scribe it as a scroll, but Player's Options: Spells & Magic states the exact opposite (plus rules for ingredients to be more common). I always give players the better option when published materials are contradictory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using scrolls does require a Powers Check.**

Page 118 from Realms of Terror (the Red Box Set):

"If a magical item imitates a spell, the item undergoes the same changes that the spell does (the Dungeon Master should consult Chapter VI for details)."

The requirement of a Powers Check is one of the changes to spells listed in that chapter.

**2nd edition doesn't specify whether creating scrolls requires a powers check, but 3rd edition does.**

The 2e rules for creating magic items in Ravenloft just state that the occurance is much rarer. The rules for scribing scrolls doesn't describe the creation processes as actually casting the spell, so RAW nothing in scroll scribing triggers a powers check.

The 3e Ravenloft campaign book does specify that creating evil magical items in Ravenloft (including potions and scrolls) requires a powers check that is even more difficult than the one for just casting the spell. The Powers consider allowing the spread of these magics through items to be even more offensive.